# How to Pick only Video From Gallery in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, file-upload, android-jetpack-compose

I am searching for a way to Upload Videos using Android Jetpack Compose and upload them using Multipart in OkHttp and Retrofit, but I can't find any tutorials online on how to pick Videos in Jetpack compose at all, I know how to do this using intent in old ways, but can't find a way to pick only Videos using compose.

And I do believe using Multipart in OkHttp will work in uploading the video to the server as well, is there a more recommended way in doing this?

Comment: Read the docs about MIME types.

Comment: `<data android:mimeType="video/*" />` add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and it's a very simple one.
All you need to use is

```
  val videoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        onResult = { uri ->
            videoUri = uri
        }
    )

val videoFile = viewModel.createTmpFileFromUri(context = context,videoUri!!, "video")
```

and you can use this Method in the ViewModel here to transform the URI into file

```
    fun createTmpFileFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, fileName: String): File? {
    return try {
        val stream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".mp4", context.cacheDir)
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream,file)
        file
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```